# center slider controls in responsive manner

Tags: css

I want to center the slider controls which you can find [here](http://goo.gl/o0L1XC)

I tried various ways like `right:0; left:0; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto` and two more.

But somehow I am not able to make it center in responsive manner so that in any view port, It always remain center.

So Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: What code have you tried? for example a jsfiddle

Comment: Its bit difficult for me to make JSFiddle. I gave link of my site in question. Won't it help you ?

Comment: Do you want to use width? What browser should it be able to work in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will centre the Your controls without needing to use width but will only really work for modern browsers:

```
.anythingSlider-minimalist-round .anythingControls {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.90;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 2%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

This method will work for older browsers but you will need a fixed width:

```
.anythingSlider-minimalist-round .anythingControls {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.90;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 190px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

There are a few other methods to centring a div on a page it might be worth while looking at some other methods here: [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are just being hidden when dropped into mobile. You can reshow them by putting this in your media query for small (mobile) screens.

```
.anythingSlider-minimalist-round .anythingControls{
  display: block !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 186px;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  right: 0;
  float: none;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the slider controls in a div that has `width:100%` and its contents set to `text-align:center`.  Position the div absolute, at bottom:20px (adjust this to set the desired offset from the bottom).  Finally, the container that contains the slider controls div needs to be set to `position:relative`.

```
div.slider-controls {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 20px;     <----- adjust this until you
}                          like the offset from the
                           bottom of the slider

div.slider-container {
  position: absolute;
}
```

I don;t know what your layout looks like, but in the above example, it is assumed that `div.slider-controls` is a child element of `div.slider-container`.